# Syntax for AHK switch statement not working

Tags: windows, autohotkey

Getting the error:

`Line Text: switch %randNumber%`

`"Error: This line does not contain a recognized action"`

```
;switches between one of the 6 user tabs

RandomizeTabSwitcher(){
    Random, randNumber, 1, 6
    
    switch %randNumber%
    {
        case 1:
        
        return
        
        case 2:
        
        return 
        
        case 3:
        
        return 
        
        . . .
    }
}
```

Not sure what the issue is here when I'm following the `switch doc` example

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Switch.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on an outdated AHK version.
Update by downloading the installer from the official page and run it.

Here's the changelog for when `Switch` was added.
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/AHKL_ChangeLog.htm#v1.1.31.00

Also, since the `Switch` command is rather new, it thankfully doesn't support legacy syntax.
I recommend you try to get rid of using legacy syntax.
So, don't wrap your variable definition in `%`s.
The correct syntax would be for example:

```
Random, randNumber, 1, 3
    
Switch, randNumber
{
    case 1: MsgBox, 1
    case 2: MsgBox, 2
    case 3: MsgBox, 3
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Totally did not expect that to be the issue

Comment: Be sure to read the edit I added in just now as well.